# original vimrc file. Where to fnd? how to restore?

Tags: javascript, vim

I was trying to set up vim to work with JavaScript (any links about that appreciated), though didn't even know what's .vimrc file. So I deleted it.  After removing and installing vim  for about 10 times... I now don't know what exactly should I do. I believe there was some default settings that I lost.  If I google for it I find bunch of different vimrc files, and if I put their content in my vimrc - whenever I start vim I get a lot of errors (assuming because I don't have all the plug ins).  also don't think that I should\can  create one and fill it little by little.

so. 
1. How do I restore my original vim state (if you think this is smtn I should do) - ? 
2. How do I set it up to work nicely with JavaScript files?
3. Possibly good vim tutorial?

OS  Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit
 Thank you guys. 
vim beginner.

Comment: Could you tell us what OS you're using? If Linux, what distribution (Ubuntu, CentOS, etc...) This will help us track down what the original file was that you seem to have deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `.vimrc` file is optional, and without it vim will use all of its defaults.

These defaults, however, are a bit conservative. If I recall correctly, vim defaults to being compatible with its predecessor (vi), which means no syntax highlighting, no line numbers, no ruler to tell you which mode you're in, no nothing.

Tim Pope's [sensible](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible/blob/master/plugin/sensible.vim) vimrc is a good point to start off.

Comment: The defaults will depend on a lot more than whether you have a `.vimrc` in your home directory. For instance, most distributions will have a few defaults in `/etc/vimrc`, which may well turn off compatibility mode, for instance. See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#initialization

Comment: It's almost a semantical thing, but I'd argue that `/etc/vimrc` is a vimrc file like any other, just not one you created yourself.

Comment: Sure, but the OP's question is, I think, about having deleted the `.vimrc` *in their home directory*, so the `/etc/vimrc` will still exist, and still be setting the defaults to what the distro maintainer intended.

Comment: That's true, I guess.

Comment: I apologize for my incompetence. As usually I didn't do smtn correctly. I've copied the file, and it's all well.

Comment: Glad to hear that! By the way, by the time you think you're ready to try your first plugins, give [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) a try. It'll make installing and configuring plugins a lot easier.

Answer (score 4):

If you hadn't customised the file at all before you started, then if it existed at all, it must have been the default for new users.

When creating a new user account, the files in `/etc/skel` are used to populate the new user's home directory; thus the file you deleted can probably be restored to its original state with the following command:

```
cp /etc/skel/.vimrc ~/.vimrc
```

That is "copy the `.vimrc` file from the skeleton directory into my home directory".

If that doesn't help, or if the file you deleted was actually the system-wide defaults (normally `/etc/vimrc` or `/etc/vim/vimrc`) then you can probably get hold of the original file from your OS's package archive.

Since you are running Ubuntu 12.04, the relevant file list seems to be this one: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/vim-common/filelist It doesn't seem to put anything into `/etc/skel`, but it does install an `/etc/vim/vimrc` which includes `/usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/debian.vim`.

You can [download the package manually from here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/vim-common/download) - the `.deb` file is just a `.tar.gz`, so `tar -xzvf foo.deb` will extract it for you to poke around. `cd` to a new empty directory before doing that, or you'll get very confused by the directories it creates!

Another thing to double check is that Ubuntu actually has multiple different vim packages, e.g. `vim-tiny`. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/27091/vim-to-replace-vi) for how to check you've installed and selected the "full" version.

Comment: /etc/skel doesn't contain vimrc or .vimrc  .   /etc/vim/vimrc file I believe was empty. that's where I put "Tim Pope's sensible vimrc".   But it doesnt seem to work properly. foe example I can't switch between insert and normal mode as I used to. I do realize that I'm a beginner and don't understand a lot.

Comment: See my edits. :) And no, `/etc/vim/vimrc` definitely shouldn't have been empty when you started.

Answer (score 1):

`.vimrc` usually is a config file under your `$HOME` directory. Itself is a vimscript too. You can put your config/mapping/plugin config/function... there, so that everytime you started your vim, the file would be automatically loaded. then you have a customized comfortable editor opened.

without this `.vimrc`, vim can start too, with default config though.

you can start vim and type `:h vimrc` to see the help doc of `vimrc`. You can take a vimrc from internet, try to understand the settings in the file. finally make your own vimrc. It will take veryveryvery long time to have a satisifed vimrc. I have used vim for about 10 years, last week I was still editing my vimrc file.

When you read others' vimrc settings, use `:h foo` to find the help information.  In this way, you know "why I set this", not "I don't know what's going on, just copied it".

The charm of vim is, it is highly customizable.  You can change it into plain notepad or programming IDE or mp3 player...

enjoy editing!

Comment: Thank you guys. Both of you sad that it suppose to act defalut without the file itself. - but I can see that it doesn't. I have a huge pain trying to edit couple of lines.

Comment: @WildAuroch: It’s important to note that without a `.vimrc`, it uses the default *Vim* settings, but your system might impose additional defaults that deleting `.vimrc` will remove, leaving only the default *Vim* settings. [IMSoP’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24346401) covers how to restore the default *system* settings.

Comment: @WildAuroch in a terminal, execute the command: `vim -u NONE` is there error msg? if there is, what is the msg?

Comment: @WildAuroch `man vim` to check what is `-u NONE`, basically it skips your vimrc file. So it means your vim installation is ok. are you sure you removed your `.vimrc`?  `ls -la $HOME/.vimrc` no output?